# How to add line breaks?

Tags: r, officer

I'm trying to add line breaks using `body_replace_all_text` or `body_add_par` but am having no joy. Using `\r\n` shows correctly in OSX TextEdit, but not in Word.

An example:

```
library(officer)
library(tidyverse)

read_docx() %>% 
  body_add_par("Oneline\r\n\r\nAnother line") %>% 
  print(target = "example.docx")
```

is there a right way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to call `body_add_par` each time you want to add a paragraph (a paragraph of text ends with a new line):

```
library(officer)
library(tidyverse)

read_docx() %>% 
  body_add_par("Oneline") %>% 
  body_add_par("Another line") %>% 
  print(target = "example.docx")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would be really nice to add a helper to add multiple lines/paras of plain text.

Comment: Thanks you. It's pretty useless in that way.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your comment @KarolDaniluk. You want me to know that this function is useless?

Comment: I mean it would be nice indeed if they added function to add plain text. Now it is very slow witch in my opinion makes it useless to generate big documents.

Comment: In fact I did. I don't try to be mean or vicious, just stating the facts. I found a simple workaround by writing all text into the txt file and using shell to open Word and paste the file content. Takes 3 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way that I found was to modify in Word.

```
library(officer)
library(tidyverse)

read_docx() %>% 
  body_add_par("Oneline(LineBreak)Another line") %>% 
  print(target = "example.docx")
```

Then in Word, press Ctrl + H and change all "(LineBreak)" to "^p".

Not a fancy idea but it worked for me as a band aid solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple workaround with splitting the string into a vector and writing each line separately. Unfortunately it is very slow.

```
library(officer)
library(tidyverse)

doc <- read_docx()
text <- "Oneline\r\n\r\nAnother line" %>% strsplit('\r\n') %>% unlist()
for (t in text){
  body_add_par(doc, t)
}
print(doc, target = "example.docx")
```