# How to add linbreaks to a table cell in officer in R

Tags: r, officer

How can I add linebreaks inside a table cell in officer?

I see the [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350416/how-to-add-line-breaks) that shows how to add paragraphs within the document, but not within table cells.

```
tbl = tibble(x = 'My first line\n my second line')

 read_docx() |>  
  body_add_table(tbl) |>
  print(target = "example.docx")
```

Does not recognize \n

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.